# NoneType' object is not callable when trying to replace symbols in list

Tags: python, replace

i want to replace every ">" symbol in list to " " symbol with this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.holidayscalendar.com/')
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
block = soup.find_all("td", class_="wphc-tbl-name")

for i in range(len(block)):
    block[i] = block[i].replace(">", " ")
    print(block)
```

but the program crashes with this error:

```
> i = i.replace(">"," ")
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

i tried replace for with while and work not with a list but with a var:

```
for i in range(len(block)):
    block_1 = block[i]
    block_1.replace(">", " ")
    print(block_1)
```

Comment: The posted code `block[i] = block[i].replace(">", " ")` does not match the code in the error message `i = i.replace(">"," ")`.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Please read your question after you post it to make sure it's formatted as you expect, especially with python questions where indentation can change the meaning of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something). Note that the error is a bit different, the cause is the same and the answers outline the way in which to investigate. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Note that `block[i]` is a `Tag` and not a `str`. A `Tag.<not_an_attribute>` will try to look for the next occurrence of a *not_an_attribute* tag.

E.g. `block[i].a` will give you the next hyperlink.

---

TL;DR use:

```
block[i].text.replace(">", " ")
```

In case you want to use replace on the raw html convert the Tag to a string before and then apply replace.